# How to find the longest days using SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thank you in advance for letting us a better student or learner.

I am using SQL SERVER management 17
I am trying to find the most consecutive days of raining. There are values of in the 'rain' columns such as 1.2 3.2 0 4.3 4.2 4.5 0 0 0. 
As you see if there was no rain, which means rainfall is '0', then ignore it.

I want to print out consecutive days of raining and first start date and in which city it happened.

For example  "Auckland 10-4-2018 10days";
i thought if i have to use 'with','row_number()', or other functions. 
Please consider that I want to use 'cursor'. Thank you.

```
DECLARE crs_FindRainingDays cursor FOR
SELECT station, rain, date FROM weather;

DECLARE @CITY VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @DAYS INT
DECLARE @DATE DATE



OPEN crs_FindRainingDays
--FETCH NEXT FROM crs_FindRainingDays INTO @CITY, @DAYS, @DATE
--WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    IF(@DAYS<>0 )
        BEGIN
         with DaysRaining as (select station, rain, date from weather),


        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            CONTINUE;
        END     

    PRINT 'THE CITY WITH MOST CONSECUTIVE RAINING DAYS IS WAS IN '+@CITY+' FOR '+@DAYS+' WHICH STARTED FROM '+@DATE;
--FETCH NEXT FROM crs_FindRainingDays INTO @CITY, @DAYS, @DATE
END
CLOSE crs_FindRainingDays
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Also, tell us which version of SQL Server you are using.  This may really matter for your question.

Comment: The expected result for your data is 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the "gaps-and-islands" solution, but here's a slightly different way to get the answer, that also deals with cases where there's a tie for the most consecutive rainy days (which I would imagine happens often?).

First I created some test data:

```
DECLARE @d TABLE (
    station VARCHAR(50),
    rain INT,
    [date] DATE)
INSERT INTO @d SELECT 'Auckland', 1, '20180101';
INSERT INTO @d SELECT 'Auckland', 2, '20180102';
INSERT INTO @d SELECT 'Auckland', 3, '20180103';
INSERT INTO @d SELECT 'Auckland', 2, '20180104';
INSERT INTO @d SELECT 'Auckland', 0, '20180105';
INSERT INTO @d SELECT 'Auckland', 4, '20180106';
INSERT INTO @d SELECT 'Auckland', 3, '20180107';
INSERT INTO @d SELECT 'Auckland', 4, '20180108';
INSERT INTO @d SELECT 'Auckland', 2, '20180109';
INSERT INTO @d SELECT 'Auckland', 4, '20180110';
INSERT INTO @d SELECT 'Auckland', 5, '20180111';
INSERT INTO @d SELECT 'Auckland', 0, '20180112';
INSERT INTO @d SELECT 'Manchester', 9, '20180101';
INSERT INTO @d SELECT 'Manchester', 9, '20180102';
INSERT INTO @d SELECT 'Manchester', 9, '20180103';
INSERT INTO @d SELECT 'Manchester', 9, '20180104';
INSERT INTO @d SELECT 'Manchester', 9, '20180105';
INSERT INTO @d SELECT 'Manchester', 9, '20180106';
INSERT INTO @d SELECT 'Manchester', 9, '20180107';
INSERT INTO @d SELECT 'Manchester', 0, '20180108'; --instrumentation error?
```

The query might look longer, but that's mainly because of the spacing I am using, also the `DENSE_RANK()` step to handle ties.

```
WITH Base AS (
    SELECT
        station,
        [date] AS d,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY station ORDER BY [date]) i
    FROM 
        @d
    WHERE
        rain > 0
    GROUP BY
        station,
        [date]),
Ranges AS (
    SELECT
        station,
        MIN(d) AS [start_date],
        MAX(d) AS end_date,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(d), MAX(d)) AS [days],
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(d), MAX(d)) DESC) AS rank_id
    FROM 
        Base
    GROUP BY
        station,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, i, d))
SELECT
    station,
    [start_date],
    end_date,
    [days]
FROM
    Ranges
WHERE
    rank_id = 1;
```

So how does this work?  Let's break the query down into the various parts; here's the results from the first CTE (Base):

```
station     d           i
Auckland    2018-01-01  1
Auckland    2018-01-02  2
Auckland    2018-01-03  3
Auckland    2018-01-04  4
Auckland    2018-01-06  5
Auckland    2018-01-07  6
Auckland    2018-01-08  7
Auckland    2018-01-09  8
Auckland    2018-01-10  9
Auckland    2018-01-11  10
Manchester  2018-01-01  1
Manchester  2018-01-02  2
Manchester  2018-01-03  3
Manchester  2018-01-04  4
Manchester  2018-01-05  5
Manchester  2018-01-06  6
Manchester  2018-01-07  7
```

So all we did here was to sort the readings into station, then date order, applying an incremental counter to each station's readings.  There are 10 readings for the first station, and 7 for the second station, so our counters run 1-10 and 1-7.

Next is the Ranges CTE, but there are a few steps here, so I will first break down the detail of this CTE by using this query:

```
SELECT
    station,
    i,
    d,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, i, d) AS group_item
FROM 
    Base;
```

Which shows how the grouping works:

```
station     i   d           group_item
Auckland    1   2018-01-01  43098
Auckland    2   2018-01-02  43098
Auckland    3   2018-01-03  43098
Auckland    4   2018-01-04  43098
Auckland    5   2018-01-06  43099
Auckland    6   2018-01-07  43099
Auckland    7   2018-01-08  43099
Auckland    8   2018-01-09  43099
Auckland    9   2018-01-10  43099
Auckland    10  2018-01-11  43099
Manchester  1   2018-01-01  43098
Manchester  2   2018-01-02  43098
Manchester  3   2018-01-03  43098
Manchester  4   2018-01-04  43098
Manchester  5   2018-01-05  43098
Manchester  6   2018-01-06  43098
Manchester  7   2018-01-07  43098
```

The "trick" here is that the `DATEDIFF(DAY, i, d)` identifies contiguous rows, so for Auckland we have one group 43098 that runs from 01-01-2018 to 04-01-2018, then there's a gap for 05-01-2018, then a second group 43099 that runs from 06-01-2018 to 11-01-2018.  The actual numbers don't matter, just the fact that this allows us to identify our "islands".

So for each island we want to do the following:

- group on the number generated by `DATEDIFF(DAY, i, d)`;
- find the `MIN(d)` as the first date in the range;
- find the `MAX(d)` as the last date in the range;
- count the number of days in the range as the difference between the two dates calculated above;
- rank by the number of days, but allow for ties.

So our actual output from the Ranges CTE looks like this:

```
station start_date  end_date    days    rank_id
Manchester  2018-01-01  2018-01-07  6   1
Auckland    2018-01-06  2018-01-11  5   2
Auckland    2018-01-01  2018-01-04  3   3
```

...and our final query is simply to pick the row(s) with a rank_id of 1, pulling out the station name, the start date, the end date, and the number of days.

Comment: Is it possible to user 'cursor' and 'while @@fetch status ==0'. Just wonder if i can use these functions and use them to make a query.

Comment: There's no reason to use a cursor here that I can see.  In fact cursors are usually frowned on as being bad design (row-by-row is almost always less efficient than set-based querying).  Could you use a cursor here just "because"?  Probably not as the DENSE_RANK() will only work properly over the entire set.  I suppose you could do something forced like dump the data to a temporary table, then use a cursor to pull it out again, but that would just be weird.

Comment: Can you please explain how DATEDIFF(DAY, i,d) works? 'i' is row_number meaning integer, but it works fine with DATEDIFF function. 'i' means row_number and 'd' means date which looks like no bearing on row number(). How 'group by' works with 'datediff' function? Sorry, it was hard to understand.

Comment: It's the same trick as Gordon uses in his answer, taking the difference between two values and grouping by them.  The slight change here is that one value is a date and one is an integer.  You can't subtract an integer from a date by typing `i - d`, but you can use DATEDIFF and pass an integer as one or both values, for example try this: `SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, 1, 2);` and you will get an answer of 1 "day"...

Comment: It doesn't actually matter what the answer is, i.e. how many "days" there are between i and d, simply that each difference gets a separate grouping.

Comment: There's a more complete explanation here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167068/solving-gaps-and-islands-with-row-number-and-dense-rank

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I tried to understand the part how can you find the min(date) and max(date) with what conditions. As you know the raw data of date is listed in a row, how do you find the consecutive days and make it "days"?. Sorry if that is too basic stuff. Thank you.

Comment: I edited my answer, adding some more information on how this actually works.  It's basically just a clever trick that someone discovered years ago, and people have been using ever since.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a cursor.  One useful trick is the difference of row numbers.  This assumes that you have exactly one row per station on each day:

```
select top (1) station, count(*) as days_with_rain, min(date), max(date), sum(rain)
from (select w.*,
             row_number() over (partition by station order by date) as seqnum_s,
             row_number() over (partition by station, is_rain order by date) as seqnum_sr
      from weather w cross apply
           (values (case when rain > 0 then 1 else 0 end)) v(is_rain)
     ) w
group by station, (seqnum_s - seqnum_sr)
order by count(*) desc;
```

This specific problem has a name "gaps-and-islands" (yours is a minor variant of it).  Why the difference of row numbers works takes a bit of a cognitive leap.  I would suggest running the subquery and staring at the results.  You should see how the difference between the two row number values provides the information you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You gave me a good insight. But the question is I should use 'cursor' to solve the problem. I never learned 'cross apply' before. i feel like it is too advanced as I just started learning 'cursor' part from basics.

Comment: @JayceLila . . . If you have a set-based alternative, then you pretty much never want to use a cursor.